# How to use multiple WebBrowser DocumentCompleted

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I would like to be able to open a web page, log in, and be able to do things on the next page. DoPlans will not execute. Here is my code so far... (I do know that I have t for a lot of the variables)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.Navigate("t");
    }

    private void DoPlans(object sender,
WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText("started");
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("t").InvokeMember("Click");
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("t").InvokeMember("Click");
        foreach (HtmlElement elem in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
        {
            if (elem.GetAttribute("value") == "Submit Weekend Plans")
            {
                elem.InvokeMember("Click");
            }
        }
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", "t");
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", "t");
        foreach (HtmlElement elem in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
        {
            if (elem.GetAttribute("value") == "Login")
            {
                webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(DoPlans);
                elem.InvokeMember("Click");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're subscribing to an event inside event's own event handler. Does seem to be the right approach.

Comment: I see you're searching for an element and firing a click on it. But you're subscribing to wrong event. If click works indeed then web browser will navigate to another page. And here the same event handler should fire for the 2nd time. You just need to distinguish between different pages. You can try to use `e.Url`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Url.ToString())
    {
        case "home page":
        {
            // fire click
            break;
        }
        case "next page":
        {
            // handle logged in user
            break;
        }
    }
}
```